# Get record not more than 7 days of posting

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get record which is not more than 7 days of posting .

```
 CreatedDate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

is it correct query to get record ,
Please come to know that `CreatedDate` is column of date and time
Thanks

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: is it correct query , try to know

Comment: Is it? Just do it like NIKE said.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Your computer will not burn if you try to see if it works ...

Answer (score 0):

If I get the question you are **not** asking, the problem is that `CreatedDate` is a `DateTime` field, and you either want a `Date` answer or you are worried that `DATE_SUB` and `CURDATE` return a `Date` value.

If it is the latter, fear not, as the result will be in `DateTime` format.

If it is the former, you can cast the result to `Date` in your query.

Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3614ea/1) example.